# Toggle a loop on and off in a multi-processed program in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, simulation

I am currently running a simulation program in Python that requires me to run a large number of processes.  Each of these processes has a loop that executes a certain block of code.

The problem I am facing is that I need to processes to run for an unknown amount of time (until my experiment is complete).  There is no way to know the value of this time beforehand.

I am looking for a way to terminate the processes or simply have them stop executing when the experiment is complete.

Currently, I have created a flag variable using the Manager in Python's multiprocessing module.  Each of the child processes contain a loop that only executes while this flag is set to true.  This solves the problem but generates many errors, one for each process, when the toggle flag is set to false.

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python33\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
  self.run()
File "C:\Python33\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 95, in run
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Michael\PycharmProjects\untitled1\pmonitor.py", line 33, in backgroundTaskLauncher
  while flag[0]:
File "<string>", line 2, in __getitem__
File "C:\Python33\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 726, in _callmethod
  conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
File "C:\Python33\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 207, in send
  self._send_bytes(buf.getbuffer())
File "C:\Python33\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 281, in _send_bytes
  ov, err = _winapi.WriteFile(self._handle, buf, overlapped=True)
BrokenPipeError: [WinError 232] The pipe is being closed
Process Process-20:
```

---

I am wondering if there is a proper way to do what I am trying to go for here.  I'm not even sure if I'm using the correct terminology.

The code from the main process is as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    flag = manager.list([True])
    for taskSize in taskSizes:
        flag[0] = True
        for i in range(1,TASK_LAUNCHERS):
            Process(target=backgroundTaskLauncher, args=(taskSize,flag)).start()
            #Experiment goes here
        flag[0] = False
```

The code from the process launched is:

```
def backgroundTaskLauncher(taskSize,flag):
    while flag[0]:
        for i in range(0,CHUNK_AMOUNT):
            Thread(target=task, args=(taskSize,)).start()
            sleep(MICROCHUNK_GAP)
        sleep(INTERCHUNK_GAP*random.random()*2)
```

Essentially the main method calls a number of backgroundTaskLauncher processes who, in turn, launch many threads while the toggle flag is enabled and stop and complete when the flag is disabled.

I am looking for the proper way to go about getting this behavior.

Comment: I would suggest uploading _some_ code.

Comment: You're asking us to debug a problem in code we can't see. That's very hard to do.

Comment: Sorry about that, I added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing to join your child processes before the program ends. So the child processes are left without their daddy ;-)

Try this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    flag = manager.list([True])
    for taskSize in taskSizes:
        flag[0] = True
        processes = [] # a list to store the process handles 
        for i in range(1,TASK_LAUNCHERS):
            p = Process(target=backgroundTaskLauncher, args=(taskSize,flag))
            p.start()
            processes.append(p) # save process handle
        # Experiment goes here (I think it goes here (unindented(?)))
        flag[0] = False
        # after you are done with your experiment, join all child processes
        for p in processes:
            p.join()
```

Comment: Your're welcome. If you think that answers your question correctly, joust mark the answer as "accepted", which indicates that the problem is solved. (Comments are meant to detail information on questions or answers.)